# Object oriented schemes for Codeigniter

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, object

I want to be clear on this one. I am using codeigniter.

What/Which is the better/proper/standard/most appreciated way of OOP design in codeigniter in building web applications?

Generally,

I. **Creating a custom class like User and have a login function?** Like,

```
     class User{ 
            var $db, $id, $username, $password, $role; //have all user attributes here

            function __construct() {
               //instance for accessing the database
               $this->db =& get_instance();
            }

            public function login(){
                //do the login here
                $this->db->load->model('user_model');   
                $success = $this->db->user_model->login($this->username, $this->password);      
                //isn't this redundant using models? or should I rename the model function name like checkLogin?
                return $success;
            }

            //other class functions 
        }
```

OR

II. **Directly calling a login function in the model from the controller without creating a user object?**

O_o

In scheme 1, I am making the model to query ONLY in the database.
I can also make 'User' object to be inherited like for 'Client', 'Admin' and add specific functions for each object. I have the advantage to make the CI controller to focus in the layout and passing of variables to the view, which is primarily its purpose(not quite sure) and let the my custom classes/objects tackle operations in my web app. 
**BUT** i feel a redundancy in my login function where I called another login function in the model. Is this good?

While in scheme 2, is it proper to let my controllers handle all operations like login, register, or create a log AND receiving input posts and passing of variables to the view?

I really need some guide. 
My OO skills needs to grow.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers. @painkiller, yes, I am already using PhpActiveRecord which maps my database to my models. I'm doing this with Bonfire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I think it would be useful for you to read this arrticle:

[Access Control List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)

I'm working on a project now that uses CodeIgniter and the approach that we are using here maybe will suit you too. If you need to check for authorisation, I think the best place to do this is in the constructor of the class with calling a login function if the user is not registered yet. But it is a little bit general approach so if you have classes where some functions should be available only to registered users then you should make the  check inside the function.

Comment: Thank for your answer. What I'm really concerned about is not the login function but how could I implement OO in Codeigniter.

Comment: Maybe I don't get you question right, and I'm learning just as you, but gonna mention few things that I've learned working with CI. Most important - it's MVC based framework so it somewhat force you to write correct OO code. All manipulations including data should be done in models. Data could be anything from - info collected from a form to files and streams. If a current function in a controller expects a certain kind of user you should call a model to check this and get the result from there. You can do it in the controller but this is not the idea in the CI's MVC pattern.

Comment: Yes, I understand that MVC's are OO. This is what I have in mind.
1 - It is better to have an object like 'User'. By then you can make it a parent of objects 'Client' and 'Admin' so that you can also customize or add functions specifically to the child. For example, an 'Admin' may have a function viewClientLogs() or changeTemplateFile() bearing in mind that it inherets from the object 'User' also have a username and password. So in my admin/login (controller/action) I will not recode a login script, I will just use $admin = new Admin; $admin->login(); and redirect to admin dashboard.

Comment: 2- I want to let the controller handle the object instances, passing of variables to views(vice versa) with plain logic while it adjusts the template and view location. 
3 - Models should ONLY query in the database. 


These ideas contradicts that models can act as an object(real object in my web app like 'User'). What I mean is we can set attributes to models like $user_model->username??
I'm confused in these part. I'm looking for the defacto way. Sorry for the hustle question. T_T

Comment: Well, sorry, but I think we are looking from two different angles. And I think this could be refered to the Inversion of Control pattern. In my opinion you don't need `user` class at all. You can manipulate users using sessions and I think that it's better, easier, maybe both, to have a flag like `$_SESSION['user_role']`. This way everytime when you call a function that only certain users can access you just have to check for the user role - admin, customer, and decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to follow strict OO model you should consider using DataMapper. Many will say it will slow down the application, true, but this is the price you pay for full OO. What you can do is create a User class that handles all the data manipulation and move the login to a Auth library, that would work with your User model. And remember Models work with/do data manipulation Controllers store the business logic.I am also learning and hope this post helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to create an object and load the module in the constructor if this model will be used for more times.

But I don't recommend you to use  `$this->db =& get_instance();` in constructor. This should have been already autoloaded.

Comment: How do you autoload get_instance function?